# Can an interesting (as in doesn't reduce to the classical one) definition of complete theory be given for multi-valued logics?

Tags: logic

I'm somewhat aware of how [deduction, satisfiability etc.](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2099/3490/Hanle.pdf) are treated in multi-valued logics (using designated values and so forth. And also with [Suszko’s critique/thesis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-values/suszko-thesis.html), which more or less attacks these on the grounds of the binary membership relation in the designated set. (As I understand Malinowski’s rejection of that critique, it relies on designating different sets in the antecedent vs the consequent.)

But I've not seen a notion of [complete theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory) defined for those multi-valued logics. Is an interesting definition (i.e. something that doesn't reduce to the classical one) possible?

Comment: It's possible but not that straightforward, e.g., it's a famous result that Kleene's 3-valued logic K3 has no tautologies since if any variable of a truth function is assigned the Undetermined truth value U its result cannot be the designated value. Also with K3's natural conditional semantics it's impossible to have deduction theorem from its valid Modus Ponens inference rule! Thus it's hard to do reasoning as a chain of conditional inference expressed in the object language. You either define some new conditional or use [3 sided sequent calculus](https://www.logic.at/multlog/kleene.pdf)...

Comment: *We first present a 3-sided sequent calculus in section 3. The fundamental idea
for many-sided sequent calculi for finite-valued logics goes back to Schr¨oter [11],
Rousseau [8], Takahashi [13]. We follow the method given by Baaz, Ferm¨uller,
and Zach [4] and Zach [14] for constructing inference rules. This guarantees
that our system automatically has soundness and completness theorems, cut elimination theorem and Maehara lemma (interpolation). For proofs of these
results see [4, 14]...* So you could form a consistent, sound and complete MVL calculus system but it's very complicated...

Comment: So a safe "corollary" from this perhaps is if someone claims to commonly reason with MVL as a human using its inference rules it should be very doubtful, MVLs are thus mostly applied in electronic circuits design and testing and optimization of finite automata...

Comment: @DoubleKnot SQL uses a multi-valued logic and it has proven very useful and powerful for solving general data problems. Also, it is arguable that people actually use fuzzy logic in their day to day lives, which is a multi-valued logic.

Comment: @DavidGudeman indeed that's the tricky and confusing part, one can easily claim to understand and apply the multi-valued truth values in some use cases with intended truth table semantics, but it's really in a ad hoc manner. To strictly use MVL's inference rules as part of a sound, complete and cut-free consistent logic calculus is non-trivial as seen in my ref above...

Answer (score 0):

It usually escapes notice that the classical 2-valued material conditional has the properties of a mathematical ordering relation and the classical biconditional is a mathematical equivalence. I would claim that these properties are what make valid deduction possible.

In the case of Lukasiewicz 3-valued logic, it is possible to define a strict conditional (LCpq) and biconditional (LEpq). These do have the properties of mathematical ordering and equivalence relations and are far more satisfactory for deducibility and completeness than any of the other conditionals which may be defined in 3-valued systems.  Most of the logical equivalences proposed for 3-valued systems are biconditionals, but are not mathematical equivalences.

This is not the same as the strict conditional used in the Lewis systems of modal logic. However, if the strict Lukasiewicz conditional is true, then so is the Lewis strict conditional, although not conversely.

I have not found this possibility discussed anywhere in the literature, although it is easy enough to verify.