# Can the "doctrine of degrees of existence" be used to support the well-ordering lemma apart from the axiom of choice?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, existence, set-theory, numbers

I was pleasantly surprised to read (in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem#History)) that:

> In second order logic, however, the well-ordering theorem is strictly stronger than the axiom of choice: from the well-ordering theorem one may deduce the axiom of choice, but from the axiom of choice one cannot deduce the well-ordering theorem.

From what I recall, Zermelo disputed Cantor's vision of the well-orderable universe because he (Zermelo) thought that Cantor appealed too much to temporal intuition, applying the dynamical ordering of time to the abstract ordering of sets. **So, however, besides the axiom of choice, has any mathematician ever developed an alternative basis for the well-ordering lemma?**

In my own system, I've tried to see if I could fine-tune the theory of the justification function to involve only well-ordered outputs. For example, if j(*S*) = 0, or 1, or 2, or... And then to say that j(*S*) only equals well-orderable numbers. I've also thought of adapting [Quentin Smith's "degree presentism"](https://philpapers.org/rec/SMITAD-3) to the case, waiving the temporal qualifiers but otherwise importing the renewed "doctrine" of "degrees of existence." I keep the notion of existence-as-quantification by distinguishing between:

1. "∃<sub>κ</sub>*x*" = "There is at least one *x*."
2. "∃<sub>α</sub>*x* = *X*" = "The degree of *x*'s existence is *X*."

Hypothetically: there might be an *a priori* principle of existence, here, such that:

3. ∃<sub>κ</sub>*x* → ∃<sub>α</sub>*x* > 0
4. And... ∃<sub>α</sub>*x* > 0 → ∃<sub>κ</sub>*x*

But it would be interesting to toy around with the question of whether something might not be quantified over, and yet would have a nonzero (or positive) degree of existence. Anyway, as far as defending the well-ordering lemma goes, the idea would be to set up the logic/set theory so that unorderly (or outright disorderly!) sets have either no degree of existence (because they do not "partake of" the ordinals that *are* the degrees in the right way?) or a degenerate degree (a degenerate finite or perhaps better [parafinite](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-long-shadow-of-the-parafinite-three-scenes-from-the-prehistory-of-a-concept) such degree), infinitesimal maybe, or "vanishingly small" (while not necessary equivalent to oblivion).

**The axiom would probably (if said aloud) sound something like, "Existence in itself is well-orderly, so that everything that exists is subject to the well-ordering of existence in itself."** How? All I've come up with so far is to say that if the elementary question of something's existence is whether it is quantified over by 0 or 1, then the elementary question of the essence of existence adverts to numbers that are well-orderly *already and apart from the explicit choice axiom*. This is not proof that all numbers partake of the character of the finite ones, in this context (they certainly are not co-participants by the by, seeing as infinite numbers *are not finite*, after all!), but only meant to indicate what I would have to be presuppose/prove moreover.

Comment: Your highly speculative *degree of existence* (DOE) goes the same route of multi-valued logic (MVL) which sounds rational but to setup a complete/consistent logic calculus is highly complicated which is not human-oriented as discussed in a recent [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92462/can-an-interesting-as-in-doesnt-reduce-to-the-classical-one-definition-of-com). In 2nd order logic ranging over sets of every combo of already arbitrarily shaped ZFC sets, there're simply so many sets that only a partial order can be safely drawn with multiple parallel choice (AC) paths...

Comment: Thus well-ordering is highly suspected at the utmost foundational level which is consistent with the idea that Fregean logicism's Kantian natural number *intuition* is nothing but an *illusion*. The idea is in set theory such as ZFC with axiom of infinity, there're multiple ways to produce equivalent intended models of PA as Von Neumann and Zermelo numbers, etc, which hints that natural numbers are not fundamental atoms...

Comment: So far, my approach to the Benacerraf identification/implementation problem is to code each "known" format (2 = {{0}} vs. 2 = {0, 1}, etc.) as having a fractional justification value, so that the "ideal" is a format that combines the *modus operandi* of the others, so that its justification value = 1/n + 1/m + ... = 1/(n + m + ...) = 1/1 = 1. But how to apply this notion so far escapes me (I do have that 2 = {1} and then 3 = {2}, but 4 = {2, 3} or rather {0, {0}, {{0}}, {{{0}}}}; so 4 is either the first ordered *pair* or at least the first number in von Neumann format).

Comment: Never heard of [Benacerraf identification problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benacerraf%27s_identification_problem) before, looks like I found it independently! See also [Benacerraf's epistemological problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Benacerraf#Philosophical_work), seems your effort is doomed to fail as he already showed non-isomorphism of different set-theory encoding schemes in their meta-system...

Comment: I expect some things won't "go away." Like the ability to code all numbers in binary. Of course, vs. the alephs, I have to conceive of languages with infinitely many letters in their alphabets. Or there are infinitely many numerals, one for each *n* individually. Anyway, the reason for 2 = {{0}} is because 0 is actually replaced with U, for an ur-element, locked inside the number 1. So it is not an element of 2, and so 2 must be {{U}}. It would be amiss is 3 = {1, 2}, so we set 4 to {2, 3} and proceed. Not much going for it besides sheer aesthetics, maybe...

Comment: Well, if in NFU like set theory which has Quine atom U={U}, then your reasoning 0 is not a member of 2 seems doesn't apply...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, Quine's ur-element is not an ur-element strictly (a strict ur-element is not a set/has no elements under it, whereas the Quine singleton has an element, albeit it is its own element). In my system, U exists to serve one purpose, to make 1 into a set with 1 element, such that 1 is the only set of this element, and U is the only element of that set. There is a "narrative" reason for this at best, I suppose (and I must allow for other set-theoretic universes with other "narratives").